# Beginning DirectX 11 Game Programming Error

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-errors

Here is the code that it gives me on page 33:

```
#include<Windows.h>

int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE prevInstance,
       LPWSTR cmdLine, int cmdShow)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER( prevInstance );
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER( cmdLine );
    WNDCLASSEX wndClass = { 0 };
    wndClass.cbSize = sizeof( WNDCLASSEX ) ;
    wndClass.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wndClass.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wndClass.hInstance = hInstance;
    wndClass.hCursor = LoadCursor( NULL, IDC_ARROW );
    wndClass.hbrBackground = ( HBRUSH )( COLOR_WINDOW + 1 );
    wndClass.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wndClass.lpszClassName = "DX11BookWindowClass";
    if( !RegisterClassEx( &wndClass ) )
    return -1;
    RECT rc = { 0, 0, 640, 480 };
    AdjustWindowRect( &rc, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, FALSE );
    HWND hwnd = CreateWindowA( "DX11BookWindowClass", "Blank Win32 Window",
    WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, rc.right - rc.
    left,
    rc.bottom - rc.top, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL );
    if( !hwnd )
    return -1;
    ShowWindow( hwnd, cmdShow );

    return 0;
}
```

This code gives me 2 errors-

> 1>------ Build started: Project: BlankWindow, Configuration: Debug
>   Win32 ------ 1>  main.cpp 1>c:\coding\c++\visual
>   c++\directx\blankwindow\blankwindow\main.cpp(10): error C2065:
>   'WndProc' : undeclared identifier 1>c:\coding\c++\visual
>   c++\directx\blankwindow\blankwindow\main.cpp(15): error C2440: '=' :
>   cannot convert from 'const char [20]' to 'LPCWSTR' 1>          Types
>   pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast,
>   C-style cast or function-style cast
>   ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Basically

> 'WndProc' : undeclared identifier And '=' : cannot convert from 'const
>   char [20]' to 'LPCWSTR'

What is wrong with this code?

Comment: I put the code into the question (rather than using an external link). Also, what is `page 33` referring to? And where is your `WndProc`? Do you know what a [windows procedure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632593%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is?

Comment: No, am I supposed to know WinAPI before DirectX?

Comment: @GreyerSting: Well, since a DirectX application is by definition *windowed*, it would probably be a good idea to know how windows work ;)

Comment: @GreyerSting: If you don't have a good understanding of the WinAPI and C++, you will have a *very* hard time with DirectX. DirectX is huge and complicated, just setting up the boilerplate code will take a few hundred lines.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a basic working program of your code:

```
#include<Windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
            {
                    case WM_CLOSE:
                            DestroyWindow(hwnd);
                            break;
                    case WM_DESTROY:
                            PostQuitMessage(0);
                            break;
                    default:
                            return DefWindowProc(hwnd,
                                                 message,
                                                 wParam,
                                                 lParam);
            }
    return 0;
}

int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE prevInstance,
       LPSTR cmdLine, int cmdShow)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER( prevInstance );
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER( cmdLine );
    WNDCLASSEX wndClass = { 0 };
    wndClass.cbSize = sizeof( WNDCLASSEX ) ;
    wndClass.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wndClass.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wndClass.hInstance = hInstance;
    wndClass.hCursor = LoadCursor( NULL, IDC_ARROW );
    wndClass.hbrBackground = ( HBRUSH )( COLOR_WINDOW + 1 );
    wndClass.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wndClass.lpszClassName = "DX11BookWindowClass";
    if( !RegisterClassEx( &wndClass ) )
    return -1;
    RECT rc = { 0, 0, 640, 480 };
    AdjustWindowRect( &rc, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, FALSE );
    HWND hwnd = CreateWindowA( L"DX11BookWindowClass", L"Blank Win32 Window",
    WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, rc.right - rc.
    left,
    rc.bottom - rc.top, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL );
    if( !hwnd )
    return -1;
    ShowWindow( hwnd, cmdShow );
    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage (&msg, 0, 0, 0))
            {
                TranslateMessage (&msg);
                DispatchMessage (&msg);
            }
    return msg.wParam;
}
```

Points:

1. I added a `WndProc` which handles all messages sent to your program.
2. I added a [message loop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644928%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to your program. Otherwise, the window would close right away.
3. I added the `L` prefix as suggested by the_mandrill in the other answer.

This is pretty much your "Hello World" of WinAPI programming. However, I strongly suggest you learn the WinAPI first before jumping into DirectX programming.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the project is being built as [Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode), but your code is non-Unicode. In other words the Windows API calls are expecting wide (ie 16-bit) strings but your code uses 8-bit strings ('char').  `LPCWSTR` means *long pointer to a constant wide string*. So the function call is expecting a constant wide string, but you're passing an 8-bit string.  You have two options:

- Change the project to use the non-Unicode libraries (Properties -> General -> Character Set = 'Use Multi-byte')
- Fix up your code to make it Unicode. In this case by changing the strings it is complaining about to make them into wide strings. You can do this by prefixing them with `L`, eg `L"DX11BookWindowClass"`

Comment: Thanks, the second one fixed the problem.  I still am having trouble with WndProc, though.